# ¿Como consultar entidades relacionadas con sintaxis de métodos entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Como escribo esta misma consulta pero con la sintaxis de método?

```
var rec = from r in bd.Recurso
                      join u in bd.RecursoUsuario on r.IdRecurso equals u.IdRecurso
                      where u.IdUsuario == idUsuario
                      select r;
```

Algo similar a:

```
List<Recurso> re = bd.Recurso.Include("RecursoUsuario")
                    .Where(x => x.RecursoUsuario.IdUsuario == id)
                    .ToList();
```

Teniendo en cuenta que `idUsuario` es el parámetro y obviamente no es ese el valor.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Una forma en que podrias realizarlo es asi:

```
var rec = bd.Recurso
    .Join(bd.RecursoUsuario,
        r => r.IdRecurso,
        u => u.IdRecurso,
        (r , u) => new { Recurso = r, Usuario = u })
    .Where(ru => ru.Usuario.IdUsuario == idUsuario)
    .Select(ru => ru.Recurso);
```

Personalmente prefiero usar sintaxis de query en joins ya que son mas claras de leer y al final el rendimiento es el mismo que con sintaxis de métodos.

Espero esto resuelva tu problema.